# Looking to repeat a word every frame until a 1000×1000 Canvas is covered

Tags: recursion, text, processing

Right now I'm generating geometric figures in processing for a sort of art narrative comic, but for the intro sequence I'd like to have the word, "scan." Repeat on screen until the whole screen is covered, each word touching end to end. If it could be initiated on click that'd be awesome.

I can get text to appear of course, but this kind of repetition isn't something I'm familiar with at all.

Let me know if you need me to post what I'm currently working with.

Thanks!

Comment: @cybermonkey Please notice the [tag:processing] tag. Processing is a programming language.

Comment: @KevinWorkman My bad, the tag should probably be renamed as it's not obvious what it is until you view the wiki (and language tags should always be first).

Comment: @cybermonkey That has been discussed previously [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java).

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Store the current state (where the next word should be drawn) in variables at the top of your sketch.

**Step 2:** Inside the `draw()` function, use those variables to draw **one frame** of your animation.

**Step 3:** Then just update the variables holding your state to point to the next place. Processing will call the `draw()` function 60 times per second, so this will create an animation.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on animation in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).

Comment: @Kevin_workman Thanks! That sounds good but I'm honestly not sure how to call the update the variable, could I find that in your tutorial?

Comment: @DanG You don't really call anything to update a variable, you just modify the value of the variable. The tutorial contains examples that update variables to show moving balls using code like `y = y+1`. You would have to do something similar, but with the coordinate the next word should be drawn.